# Как полностью обновить активити?

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Как можно полностью обновить активити? Т.е пересоздать его, как это происходит при переворачивании экрана.

Comment: Я затрудняюсь придумать, когда это может понадобиться. Прочитайте ещё раз о состояниях Activity. В крайнем случае, если Вам нужно именно дизайн Activity пересоздать, то для этого нужно воспользоваться классом LayoutInflater. И обязательно это всё должно вызываться в главном потоке!

Comment: yorActivity.recreate();

Comment: придумал кое-что. при клике на кнопку я открываю новое такое же активити, и сразу после этого удаляю старое методом finish(). насколько это правильно?

Comment: самый главный вопрос - зачем? задавай его себе всегда когда начинаешь проектировать велосипед  
пересоздать Activity это довольно затратные операции, моей фантазии не хватает придумать ситуацию в которой это может пригодится

Comment: нужно просто вынести всю инициализацию из onCreate() в др. функцию, и просто вызвать эту функцию, когда нужно "обновить активити"

Comment: @gadfil при смены локали к примеру иногда может пригодится, если некоторые элементы(tabbar) к примеру не хочет переводиться.

Answer (score 6):

**Метод класса Activity:**

```
 <YourActivity`sName>.recreate();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = new Intent( this , this.getClass() );    
finish();    
this.startActivity(i);
```